# I want to find the entries which doesn't match with given pattern in the list and the list name is a variable

Tags: tcl

I want to find the entries in a list which doesn't match with a given pattern. Where the list name is variable. I want to do this in a for loop.

For example:

```
set li {{1 2} {1 3} {-1 -1}}

lsearch -all -inline -exact -not $li {-1 -1}
```

> Ans: {1 2} {1 3}.

But my problem is, i want to give a variable name in place "li". li will vary in a loop.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Is it with assembling the list being searched, or the pattern being used to filter the list? Or something else? (The `lsearch` really doesn't care how you create the list or pattern; that all goes on before it gets hold of things.)

Comment: When you say _'i want to give a variable name in place of "li"', what do you mean? Are you referring to the first statement or the second?

Comment: Hi, The list in i want to use will vary in for loop depends on the index.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that includes some sample data in the actual format, along with a for loop where you are trying to process that data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. I'm assuming when you say *'i want to give a variable name in place "li"'* that you mean you want to use a variable to designate the name of another variable.

You can do that using `set`:

```
set varname li
lsearch -all -inline -exact -not [set $varname] {-1 -1}
```

When you do `[set $varname]`, tcl will first substitute "li" for `$varname`. That transforms the statement to `lsearch ... [set li] ...`, and `[set li]` is functionally identical to `$li`.